# Powershell Start-Service access denied running as Domain Admin

Tags: powershell

Trying to run simple commands such as,

`set-service -name WinRM -StartupType Automatic` are giving me access denied errors as a domain admin.

Local admin works, but I'm trying to run these commands remotely without interrupting the user. Where would be a good place to check why this isn't working?

I start powershell with a right click and "Run As Different User" and enter in my domain admin credentials.

Comment: How are you running it remotely? Using PowerShell remoting (e.g. `Invoke-Command`)?  If so, then the user must be a local admin on the target machine, not just the local one.  Check out [about_Remote_Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-6) for some suggestions on what to check.

Comment: Why aren't you setting this up through GPO?

Comment: At the moment I'm not running it remotely. I'm running it on my local machine using my domain admin credentials just to test.

I'm actually using the ISE and thats when I came across the error when I tried to run it. I'm not setting it up through GPO because I don't know how. I was just trying to do something quick for an end user

Comment: Try to start an elevated ISE session by running it as admin. This is not the same as running as different user.

Comment: That would definitely work, as I'm testing the command on my own machine. I was just trying to figure out why using my domain credentials don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your powershell process is running under domain admin privileges, running the following command will make sure everything is set up for PSRemoting (service, listener, etc.):

```
$IP = Read-Host -Prompt 'IP address or hostname'

([wmiclass]"\\$IP\root\cimv2:win32_process").
    Create('powershell "Enable-PSRemoting -Force"')
```

Comment: Is it possible to continue to add commands to that same line after PSremoting is enabled?

Comment: @Fexception I mean, sure, but why?  Just use `Invoke-Command` at that point.

Comment: Because I've been using the ISE to write script and automate a lot of mundane tasks that our help desk does on a daily basis. :) And for learning purposes. Thanks!

Comment: @TheIncorrigibl1 What would be the Windows 10 version of this? I I get Cannot convert value "\\\root\cimv2:win32_process" to type "System.Management.ManagementClass". Error: "Invalid
parameter ".

So I replaced Win32_process with CIM_Process, and I get the same error. Thats the only CIM class I could assume that would go in there

Comment: @Fexception That *is* a Windows 10 version.  It's not OS-specific.  I see you're not passing a computername in your exception message.

Comment: I did, I just didn't post the entire error. It worked after the 2nd try, not sure what I was doing wrong. But the whole reason this is coming up is because I don't think the command does the whole WinRM setup process, I think I'm missing: 3. Create a listener to accept request on any IP address.
4. Enable firewall exception for WS-Management traffic (for http only).

Comment: I get this on both Win10 and Win7 devices: Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server 10.8.7.163 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot
process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is
HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure
TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.

Comment: I get that even after adding the -Credentials option when trying to run Enter-PSSession

Comment: @Fexception you're using an IP address is your problem which means it will try using NTLM instead of Kerberos. Use a DNS name or fqdn is best

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

`Set-Service 'WinRM' -Computername System01 -StartupType Automatic -PassThru | Start-Service -PassThru`

Let me know how it works for you